# How are domovye (domestic spirits) experienced in Russian flats (apartments)?

Tags: mythical-creatures, folklore, slavic, russian

In Russian culture, the [domovoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domovoi) (домовой) is a domestic house spirit. Traditionally he lives under the stove or threshold, in the cattle shed or in the stable. He is the home's guardian and if kept happy - he can be left milk, porridge, bread, and salt - he helps with the work.

Most Russians nowadays live in flats (apartments), where some continue to experience *domovye*.

Many aspects of life in flats are different from life in single-family houses in the countryside. How does this affect how people experience *domovye*? Did they appear in flats as soon as people moved in, or did they take a while to manifest? Did they follow families from their previous homes in the countryside? How are their lives and interactions with people different now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Домовой** lives in almost every home. Most often he may be found where several generations of the family lived. To reveal his presence is difficult, but if a home is not happy, he will certainly show his displeasure. He is able to protect against many misfortunes: fires, scandals, theft, ill-wishers or foes. However, if a family start show disrespect to their home, make a mess, **Домовой** becomes angry, and then you'll know exactly that he lives in that home.

People believed that without a **Домовой** there will be misfortune in the family, so when moving in the last night or before leaving the old house invited **Домовой** to a new place saying: *Ангел мой, пойдём со мной* (my angel, come with me) 3 times.

---

### Signs of the presence of the [Домовой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9) in the apartment

[image: Домовой]

#### 1. Loud noise

Sometimes at the night **Домовой** may manifest himself, rearranging the dishes in the kitchen, slamming doors, loud stomping. He usually gets mad when the hostess stops carefully monitor the cleanliness. In this case, the **Домовой** gets harmful, hides things, thereby calling for cleaning.

#### 2. Pets

The most widespread pets, cats and dogs, always see and hear more than people. If you noticed that the dog sometimes cautiously looks into the corner, starts wagging her tail and trying to play like herself, most likely, she sees **Домовой**. Also cats can suddenly freeze, and then are beginning purr, arching back, as if invisible hand caress them.

#### 3. Loss of sweets or small items

**Домовой** may steal a few candies, wrappers from which will periodically catch your eye in the most unexpected places. Also he may shift keys, scissors and other objects out of harmfulness. Pour milk in a small cup, put porridge with butter in a plate and put it in the corner. Ask **Домовой** apologize for the carelessness and ask him to guard your house with the same force. Also ask to return the lost things in exchange, for example, for marmalade.

#### 4. Dreams

In a dream **Домовой** may prompt you the solution of the problem, indicate who from the inner circle are hostile. In rare cases, **Домовой** may indicate the place where the treasure is hidden. So he shows respect, thanks for caring, but most often it is gratitude for the fact that when you moved you didn't forgot about him and offered to go to a new home.

#### 5. Safety

We often feel anxiety, but when we return home, we notice that fears gone somewhere. Peace mood appears, warmth and comfort. And at night nightmares don't torture us we easily fall asleep and wake up cheerful and rested. It is also a sign of a presence **Домовой** in the house who cares about our safety and peace of mind.

#### 6. Warning

Sometimes it also happens that at the night we suddenly wake up with a strong sense of anxiety, and in the dream feel like something swooped down and presses. So **Домовой** warns of impending danger. Also, he may make loud noise, slam the door or press the doorbell. In this case, you should take care of your safety and prevent leakage of gas, water or fire, double-checking all the important places in the house.

#### 7. Company

Often before someone without notification looks to visit unto you you will feel it. This may be intuition, but most often the **Домовой** warns of all uninvited guests in advance. A quiet knock or jingled phone alerts about people with good intentions. Sense of anxiety, suddenly crashed glass, worried pets signal, that foes want to visit your house.

#### 8. Children

**Домовой** refers to junior family members with special attention and respect, play with them and protect. Often you may notice that the child puts an extra tableware for a doll tea party, laughs loudly, says something into the void. Young mothers often notice that suddenly shouted in a dream child becomes silent, the blanket on him is corrected, and the cradle slowly swings.

#### 9. Feelings

When moving to a new home, you should carefully listen to your feelings, especially if someone lived in the new house before you. Often owners leave the apartments and houses, without taking away spirit with themselves. In this case, **Домовой** is unlikely to be friendly to you. His trust must be earned. If the feeling of anxiety don't leaves you give to the little spirit some dainty and offer friendship. In as a gift you can give him a shred of a tissue, old clothes, hay, shoe. If this is a private house, then **Домовой** necessarily choose a secluded area, where he will settle with great comfort. In apartments, **Домовой** feels more difficult because of the small space, but here he also may choose a place under the bathtub, on the entresol or in an old suitcase. If over time you have established life, you feel peace, so then **Домовой** took you for the new owners and is ready to serve. If the feeling of anxiety increases, things disappear in the house, scandals become more frequent, it is worth thinking about how to drive away the evil spirit.

#### 10. Appearance

In rare cases, **Домовой** reveals itself. If the little grey or smoky kitten implored to enter your door, let him in. **Домовой** is often embodied in these animals. It also happens that **Домовой** warns about something significant so much that dares to appear in front of us. This may be a small vague silhouette, a cat, a gray-haired old man. It is important at this point to concentrate and ask what news brought your home defender. Feel warmth - happy news wait you; cold, chills, shaking or a sense of danger - expect trouble.

---

Original article in russian: [10 признаков присутствия домового в квартире](https://dailyhoro.ru/article/10-priznakov-prisutstviya-domovogo-v-kvartire/).